# elm init, make, install and stuff inside reactor fail with HTTP PROBLEM

Tags: elm

I'm trying to run a simple counter example app (from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQjivmLan0E)):

```
import Html exposing (button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

main =
    Html.beginnerProgram {
        model = init,
        update = update,
        view = view
    }
init =
    { count = 0 }

type Msg = Increment

view model =
    div[] [
        text model.count,
        button [ onClick Increment ][ text "increment" ]
    ]

update = Increment model =
    { model | count = model.count + 1 }
```

My project folder looks like this:

```
package.json // created with npm init , npm install --save-dev elm
elm.json     // since elm init fails, copy-pasted from https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/elm.json/application.md
src/Main.elm // the file shown above
node_modules/...
```

When I try to run `elm init` (before elm.json was created) or `elm make src/Main.elm` or `elm install elm-lang/html`, I get the following error (the socket number differs):

> -- HTTP PROBLEM ----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> The following HTTP request failed:
>
> ```
> <https://package.elm-lang.org/all-packages>
> ```
>
> Here is the error message I was able to extract:
>
> ```
> HttpExceptionRequest Request { host = "package.elm-lang.org" port = 443
> secure = True requestHeaders =
> [("User-Agent","elm/0.19.0"),("Accept-Encoding","gzip")] path =
> "/all-packages" queryString = "" method = "GET" proxy = Nothing rawBody =
> False redirectCount = 10 responseTimeout = ResponseTimeoutDefault
> requestVersion = HTTP/1.1 } (InternalException (HostCannotConnect
> "package.elm-lang.org" [Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 728>: failed
> (Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT))]))
> ```

I also get the same thing when in `elm reactor` I try to open `Main.elm` (screenshot on the bottom just in case).

Is this a problem of the `elm` binary? I'm on Windows and installed elm 0.19; I've tried to disable my firewall just in case, but that didn't help.

Any ideas what can be the source of the problem? Googling gives rather irrelevant results... not sure what to do to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Is the machine you're using not connected to the internet? Can you reach `https://package.elm-lang.org/all-packages` in the browser?

Comment: @glennsl sure it is connected, but.. oh gosh, I can't reach it without tor or another proxy, presumably due to random site blocking in Russia. Thanks for the pointer, now I have to learn how to work this around. I'll probably try a VPN, but if you have better suggestions, those are appreciated

Comment: That's a weird site to be blocking… Perhaps a package name contains something naughty? If it's blocked on the DNS-level you could try adding a rule to your `hosts` file pointing to `159.89.227.162`. But judging by the error message, it looks like it might be the IP itself that is blocked.

Comment: @glennsl well, unfortunatelly, blocking of sites in Russia is not.. hm.. very consistent (they blocked even IP *ranges* especially when they tried to ban Telegram). I haven't found any direct confirmation that it is blocked by government (neither ISP splash screen is shown nor I can find IP or domain among block lists) but using VPN helped. This is definitely not just a DNS-level block, `ping 159.89.227.162` gives timeouts. I'll try to contact my ISP and ask if it is actually blocked and if they can unblock it, but until then, have to use VPN, I guess :/